# Event publish and subscribe through C# attributes

Tags: c#

Can we do event publish and subscription through C# attributes being specified on Method or property??

If Property is changed .. then we need to fire a event...
[FirePropertyChangedEvent]
  SomeProperty

Comment: In a word.. no. You'd have to create a separate event on the object, and fire that in the setter of the property. Like in the `INotifyPropertyChanged` model.

Comment: I know about INotifypropertychanged I am trying to do something like this....I have many properties.. where they have to subscribe for even notification. I want to use attirbutes instead of delegate signautre += . Can we do this with C# custom attributes....   [IwillFireEvent]SomeProperty   [IwillSubecribetoEvent]SomeOtherProperty.   Event will be fire on set of property... and subscriber will set its value on set .

Answer (score 0):

I've answered a similar question to this one, so ill copy my answer:

lets say you are using a local "speed" variable, which you want updated every time the main "speed" variable is updated...

```
public class SpeedHolder
{
    private float _speed;

    public event Action<float> OnSpeedChange;

    public float Speed
    {
        get { return _speed; }
        set { SetSpeed(value); }
    }

    public SetSpeed(float value)
    {
        _speed = value;
        if(OnSpeedChange != null)
            OnSpeedChange(_speed);
    }
}
```

now in every 'constructor' method of every script which uses a speed float variable, you need to add this line: `SpeedHolder.OnSpeedChange += ChangeSpeed;` and have a method like this one:

```
public void ChangeSpeed(value)
{
    speed = value;
}
```

Comment: I have many properties.. where they have to subscribe for even notification. I want to use attirbutes instead of delegate signautre += . Can we do this with C# custom attributes....   [IwillFireEvent]SomeProperty   [IwillSubecribetoEvent]SomeOtherProperty.

Comment: I found C# has C# event  attribute but I want write my own ..  so i am looking for help how can we do this with C# custom attributes.

Comment: Yeah, I'd love to know this too! This answer just explained how to subscribe to an event,  and nothing about the specifics of the question of how to do this with c# attributes-- please don't just copy and paste your answers from irrelevant questions!